# optimizing loop, passing parameters from external file, naming array arguments within awk

Tags: arrays, shell, loops, awk

Am an awk newbie. Using Windows-GNU gawk in UNXUTILS.

Have 2 kinds of records arranged sequentially **in date and time order** in my file(s), 30-field Order records (start with "O") where quantity is the 15th field, and 18-field Trade records (start with "T") where quantity is the 8th field. The underlying research data is historical-archival Indian stock market data spanning 15 days in April 2006, about 1000 firms, and comprising in all about 100 million separate order or trade records. My test data is 500 records for 2 dates, and some 200 firms.

**My objective at this point is only to compute for each firm and each date, that firm-date's cumulative order quantity and trade quantity.**

The raw data IS ordered by date and time (firms obviously jumbled up, just like voters who don't usually vote in alphabetical order!). And I do now have two separate text files, one containing a list of just the distinct firm symbols; and the other, the distinct dates, one per line.

I want try to complete the computations in a way that does not require making me go thru all of the records over and over again for each of the firms and dates. The basic computations given a firm=FIRM_1 and a date=DATE_1 are easy, for e.g. what I have resembles

```
# For each order record with firm_symbol = FIRM_1, date = DATE_1, 
# cumulate its Order quantity ($15).

( /^O/ && $4~/FIRM_1/ ) && $2~/DATE_1/ 
            { Order_Q[FIRM_1_DATE_1]=Order_Q[FIRM_1_DATE_1]+$15] }

# For each trade record with firm_symbol = FIRM_1, date = DATE_1, 
#cumulate its Trade quantity ($8).

( /^T/ && $4~/FIRM_1/ ) && $2~/DATE_1/ 
            { Trade_Q[FIRM_1_DATE_1]=Trade_Q[FIRM_1_DATE_1]+$8] }

END { print "FIRM_1 ", "DATE_1 ", Order_Q[FIRM_1_DATE_1], Trade_Q[FIRM_1_DATE_1] }
```

The question is how to construct an intelligent loop over all firms and dates, given the size of the underlying data. There are several related questions.

1. I know the name FIRM_1 need not be hard-coded inside this awk script, but could be given as a command line parameter. **But can one go one step further and get awk to take that name sequentially from a list of names in a separate file, one per line?** (If that's feasible, then taking dates from a list of dates would also be possible.)
2. I constructed the array argument names to hold Order quantity and Trade quantity knowing FIRM_1 and DATE_1. If we succeed in resolving 1 above, **can one construct array argument names like FIRM_1_DATE_1 and FIRM_1_DATE_1 on the fly, inside awk, while it is running? Will string concatenation to help form a name be allowed?**
3. I realize that I could use an editor macro or some such method, to combine my 2 keys, FIRM (1000 values) and DATE (15 values) into one FIRM_DATE key (15000 values) before doing any of this, in a **separate** step. If 2 above is feasible, I'm assuming there's no value to doing this. Would it help anyway?
4. In principle we are looking to hold in memory perhaps 1000 firms times 15 days times 2 variables = 30,000 cell entries in 2 arrays, ORDER_Q and TRADE_Q. Is this a lot? I use a modest Windows desktop with I think 8GB RAM.

Any suggestion or reference or example that will help reduce having to go over the original large input data several times will be very welcome. If something involves learning more not just about awk but about shell scripts, that will also be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use associative arrays.  Assuming that `$2` contains the name of the firm and `$4` the date, then:

```
awk '/^O/ { order_qty[$2,$4] += $15 }
     /^T/ { trade_qty[$2,$4] += $8  }
     END  { for (key in order_qty) { print key, "O", order_qty[key]; }
            for (key in trade_qty) { print key, "T", trade_qty[key]; }
          }'
```

That does not give you a defined order for the companies or dates in the output.  There are techniques to do that.  This makes a single pass over the data accumulating the results for all the companies and all the dates all in one turn.

```
awk '     { if (date[$4]++ == 0) date_list[d++] = $4; # Dates appear in order
            if (firm[$2]++ == 0) firm_list[f++] = $2; # Firms appear out of order
          }
     /^O/ { order_qty[$2,$4] += $15 }
     /^T/ { trade_qty[$2,$4] += $8  }
     END  { for (i = 0; i < f; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
                {
                    if ((qty = order_qty[firm_list[i],date_list[j]]) > 0)
                        print firm_list[i], date_list[j], "O", qty
                    if ((qty = trade_qty[firm_list[i],date_list[j]]) > 0)
                        print firm_list[i], date_list[j], "T", qty
                }
            }
          }'
```

If you want the firms in a specific (e.g. sorted) order, sort the firm list before printing.  GNU `awk` provides built-in sort functions.  Otherwise, you'll have to write an `awk` function to do it.  (See [Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880) or [More Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201118890) (or both) for more information on writing sort functions in `awk`.)

*Warning: untested code.*

Comment: Thanks a million. This (top part's what I've tried) worked like a charm. Second time in 24 hours an associative array suggestion has helped. The first time it saved sorting; now you saved countless extra passes over the data. My candidate loops not only look positively stupid, they make my own code harder for me to read. Will need to spend time understanding the second part. For now I don't need to sort, but will look at your references. And will try to understand the power of associative arrays better. Have used them for the first time this past 24 hours. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: to see the power of your suggestion, note that when I tried it out on the 129+ million master data set, from start to finish it took 11 minutes of calendar time. The tail was given by  
C:\Users\Murgie\..\CODE>cat ..\Output\Master_daily_unexecuted_qty.txt | tail -3
PROVOGUE∟17-APR-2006 T 185621
TUBEINVEST∟13-APR-2006 T 6876
129241620 records processed.

Comment: The last 2 comments were meant for you. I do also understand better now why you felt sorting might be needed at the end. Aligning order_qty and trade_qty will certainly be useful. May use SAS rather than AWK to do that (in part since a coauthor needs my output as input for his SAS work). -Murgie

Comment: Not sure why you're name gets edited out. But thanks. Your method also offers an easy way to avoid needing to match order and trade quantity at the end to compute unexecuted quantity, by simply carrying a running total within. -Murgie

Comment: @user3209061: When you say 'Not sure why your name gets edited out', do you mean you added `@ Jonathan Leffler` (without the spaces) and it vanished?  If so, that's because the owner of an answer (or question) is always notified of comments, even ones addressed to someone else in the list of commentators.

Comment: Tried even the 2nd part of your note. Matching different records for the same firm-date without the need for a SORT, and the loop only in the END procedure (not over the raw data) makes feasible on a small machine what I thought would require far more resources. But, despite struggling thru http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays and studying more examples, I don't fully know why date[.] and date_list[.] were both needed. I just know  it works, and that these associative arrays are pure magic, to avoid horrible SORTs and loops. Thanks a ton again. -Murgie

Comment: If someone has references in the spirit of "Associative Arrays for Dummies" or "Idiot's Guide To Associative Arrays," please let me know. Thanks. -Murgie

Comment: I think, in all honesty, that you could make do with only one of the two — the `date_list` would be the one I'd keep.  However, using both keeps a rigorous symmetry between the treatment of dates and firms.  You'd need to use a slightly different existence test to see whether you're working with a new date, for example.  I don't specifically know of an 'Associative Arrays for Dummies' book. Perl, Python, `awk` (obviously) all have such arrays, under various names (hashes, dictionaries, associative arrays). It is a very powerful concept.

Comment: Incidentally, 'More Programming Pearls' referenced at the end of the question has a chapter (column, as the books call them) on associative arrays.  And examples throughout the books use associative arrays when appropriate.

Comment: Just got More Programming Pearls. Seems a very valuable reference. The "Programming Pearls" got backordered and canceled twice at different used-book stores. Only more determined now to get it as well. Thanks.

Comment: ( $17~/_EQ\>/ ) {    if (date[$10]++ == 0) date_list[d++] = $10;                 # Dates appear in order in raw data
                     if (isin[$9]++ == 0) isin_list[i++] = $9;                   # ISINs appear out of order in raw data
                                   print $10, date[$10], $9, isin[$9], date_list[d], d, isin_list[i], i }

Comment: ( $17~/_EQ\>/ ) {    if (date[$10]++ == 0) date_list[d++] = $10;                 
                     if (isin[$9]++ == 0) isin_list[i++] = $9;                   
                                   print $10, date[$10], $9, isin[$9], date_list[d], d, isin_list[i], i }
When I try this, date_list[d] and isin_list[i] do not print, as if they've not been defined. But awk runs without syntax error.
This is an almost exact carbon copy of a suggestion I received on this thread. (contd)

Comment: My real problem now is larger and has 4 array variables instead of 2.
Because that wasn't working I went back to copying the 2-subscript example. From the GNU-AWK manual, examples in More Programming Pearls,
and from simply looking at the old example on this thread, I am unable to see what I have done wrong, unless there is some reserved letter
that I've picked. Had a hard disk failure from which I thought I had recovered. The GNU-AWK on Win-7 that I run gave me the same look and feel till
this example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're describing.  If need be, you can send me the question via email (see my profile) but please make sure it is self-contained and complete like an SO question should be: question, code, input data, desired output, actual output.  Or, maybe better, open a new question on SO?

Comment: Th goal above is simply to read transactions records, and compute the daily aggregate of the number of records or transactions, the number of shares, and the value of shares, by date, a firm-ID (ISIN), exchange and investor-ID.