# associative arrays in awk challenging memory limits

Tags: memory, awk, gawk

This is related to my recent post in [Awk code with associative arrays -- array doesn't seem populated, but no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086976/awk-code-with-associative-arrays-array-doesnt-seem-populated-but-no-error) and also to [optimizing loop, passing parameters from external file, naming array arguments within awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211827/optimizing-loop-passing-parameters-from-external-file-naming-array-arguments-w)

My basic problem here is simply to compute from detailed ancient archival financial market data, daily aggregates of #transactions, #shares, value, BY DATE, FIRM-ID, EXCHANGE, etc. Learnt to use associative arrays in awk for this, and was thrilled to be able to process 129+ million lines in clock time of under 11 minutes. Literally before I finished my coffee.

Became a little more ambitious, and moved from 2 array subscripts to 4, and now I am unable to process more than 6500 lines at a time.

Get error messages of the form:

> K:\User Folders\KRISHNANM\PAPERS\FII_Transaction_Data>zcat
>   RAW_DATA\2003_1.zip | gawk -f CODE\FII_daily_aggregates_v2.awk >
>   OUTPUT\2003_1.txt&
>
> gawk: CODE\FII_daily_aggregates_v2.awk:33: (FILENAME=- FNR=49300)
>   fatal: more_no des: nextfree: can't allocate memory (Not enough space)

On some runs the machine has told me it lacks as little as 52 KB of memory. I have what I think of a std configuration with Win-7 and 8MB RAM.

(Economist by training, not computer scientist.) I realize that going from 2 to 4 arrays makes the problem computationally much more complex for the computer, but is there something one can do to improve memory management at least a little bit. I have tried closing everything else I am doing. The error always has to do only with memory, never with disk space or anything else.

Sample INPUT:

```
49290,C198962542782200306,6/30/2003,433581,F5811773991200306,S5405611832200306,B5086397478200306,NESTLE INDIA LTD.,INE239A01016,6/27/2003,1,E9035083824200306,REG_DL_STLD_02,591.13,5655,3342840.15,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
49291,C198962542782200306,6/30/2003,433563,F6292896459200306,S6344227311200306,B6110521493200306,GRASIM INDUSTRIES LTD.,INE047A01013,6/27/2003,1,E9035083824200306,REG_DL_STLD_02,495.33,3700,1832721,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
49292,C198962542782200306,6/30/2003,433681,F6513202607200306,S1724027402200306,B6372023178200306,HDFC BANK LTD,INE040A01018,6/26/2003,1,E745964372424200306,REG_DL_STLD_02,242,2600,629200,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_D,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
49293,C7885768925200306,6/30/2003,48128,F4406661052200306,S7376401565200306,B4576522576200306,Maruti Udyog Limited,INE585B01010,6/28/2003,3,E912851176274200306,REG_DL_STLD_04,125,44600,5575000,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
49294,C7885768925200306,6/30/2003,48129,F4500260787200306,S1312094035200306,B4576522576200306,Maruti Udyog Limited,INE585B01010,6/28/2003,4,E912851176274200306,REG_DL_STLD_04,125,445600,55700000,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
49295,C7885768925200306,6/30/2003,48130,F6425024637200306,S2872499118200306,B4576522576200306,Maruti Udyog Limited,INE585B01010,6/28/2003,3,E912851176274200306,REG_DL_STLD_04,125,48000,6000000,REG_DL_INSTR_EU,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
```

Code

```
BEGIN { FS = "," } 
# For each array subscript variable -- DATE ($10), firm_ISIN ($9), EXCHANGE ($12), and FII_ID ($5), after checking for type = EQ, set up counts for each value, and number of unique values.
         ( $17~/_EQ\>/ )    {    if (date[$10]++ == 0) date_list[d++] = $10;
                                 if (isin[$9]++ == 0) isin_list[i++] = $9;
                                 if (exch[$12]++ == 0) exch_list[e++] = $12;
                                 if (fii[$5]++ == 0) fii_list[f++] = $5;
                                 }
# For cash-in, buy (B), or cash-out, sell (S) count NR = no of records, SH = no of shares, RV = rupee-value.
         (( $17~/_EQ\>/ ) && ( $11~/1|2|3|5|9|1[24]/ )) {{ ++BNR[$10,$9,$12,$5]} {BSH[$10,$9,$12,$5] += $15} {BRV[$10,$9,$12,$5] += $16} }
         (( $17~/_EQ\>/ ) && ( $11~/4|1[13]/ ))         {{ ++SNR[$10,$9,$12,$5]} {SSH[$10,$9,$12,$5] += $15} {SRV[$10,$9,$12,$5] += $16} }
 END  { 
          { print NR, "records processed."}
          { print "  " }
          { printf("%-11s\t%-13s\t%-20s\t%-19s\t%-7s\t%-7s\t%-14s\t%-14s\t%-18s\t%-18s\n",    \
           "DATE", "ISIN", "EXCH", "FII", "BNR", "SNR", "BSH", "SSH", "BRV", "SRV")  }
       { for (u = 0; u < d; u++)  
             {
              for (v = 0; v < i; v++)
                  {
                   for (w = 0; w < e; w++)
                       {
                        for (x = 0; x < f; x++)
                        #check first below for records with zeroes, don't print them
                            {    if  (BNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]] + SNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]] > 0)
                                      { BR = BNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
                                        SR = SNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
                                        BS = BSH[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
                                        BV = BRV[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
                                        SS = SSH[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
                                        SV = SRV[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
                                       { printf("%-11s\t%13s\t%20s\t%19s\t%7d\t%7d\t%14d\t%14d\t%18.2f\t%18.2f\n",    \
                                              date_list[u], isin_list[v], exch_list[w], fii_list[x], BR, SR, BS, SS, BV, SV) } }
                            }
                        }
                   }
               }
         }
  }
```

Expected output

```
 6 records processed.

DATE        ISIN            EXCH                    FII                 BNR     SNR     BSH             SSH             BRV                 SRV               
6/27/2003    INE239A01016      E9035083824200306      F5811773991200306       1       0           5655               0          3342840.15                0.00
6/27/2003    INE047A01013      E9035083824200306      F6292896459200306       1       0           3700               0          1832721.00                0.00
6/26/2003    INE040A01018    E745964372424200306      F6513202607200306       1       0           2600               0           629200.00                0.00
6/28/2003    INE585B01010    E912851176274200306      F4406661052200306       1       0          44600               0          5575000.00                0.00
6/28/2003    INE585B01010    E912851176274200306      F4500260787200306       0       1              0          445600                0.00         55700000.00
```

It is in this case that as the number of input records exceeds 6500, I end up having memory problems. Have about 7 million records in all.

For a 2 array subscript problem, albeit on a different data set, where 129+ million lines were processed in clock time of 11 minutes using the same GNU-AWK on the same machine, see [optimizing loop, passing parameters from external file, naming array arguments within awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211827/optimizing-loop-passing-parameters-from-external-file-naming-array-arguments-w)

Question: is it the case that awk is not very smart with memory management, but that some other more modern tools (say, SQL) would accomplish this task with the same memory resources? Or is this simply a characteristic of associative arrays, which I found magical in enabling me to avoid many passes over the data, many loops and SORT procedures, but which maybe work well up to 2 array subscripts, and then face exponential memory resource costs after that?

Afterword: the super-detailed almost-idiot-proof tutorial along with the code provided by Ed Morton in comments below makes a dramatic difference, especially his GAWK script tst.awk. He taught me about (a) using SUBSEP intelligently (b) tackling needless looping, which is crucial in this problem which tends to have very sparse arrays, with various AWK constructs. Compared to performance with my old code (only up to 6500 lines of input accepted on one machine, another couldn't even get that far), the performance of Ed Morton's tst.awk can be seen from the table below:

```
**filename  start      end       min        in ln   out lines
2008_1  12:08:40 AM 12:27:18 AM 0:18        391438  301160
2008_2  12:27:18 AM 12:52:04 AM 0:24        402016  314177
2009_1  12:52:05 AM 1:05:15 AM  0:13        302081  238204
2009_2  1:05:15 AM  1:22:15 AM  0:17        360072  276768
2010_1  "slept"                         507496  397533
2010_2  3:10:26 AM  3:10:50 AM  0:00         76200   58228
2010_3  3:10:50 AM  3:11:18 AM  0:00         80988   61725
2010_4  3:11:18 AM  3:11:47 AM  0:00         86923   65885
2010_5  3:11:47 AM  3:12:15 AM  0:00         80670   63059**
```

Times were obtained simply from using %time% on lines before and after tst.awk was executed, all put in a simple batch script, "min" is the clock time taken (per whatever rounding EXCEL does by default), "in ln" and "out lines" are lines of input and output, respectively. **From processing the entire data that we have, from Jan 2003 to Jan 2014, we find the theoretical max number of output records = #dates*#ISINs*#Exchanges*#FIIs = 2992*2955*567*82268, while the actual number of total output lines is only 5,261,942, which is only 1.275*10^(-8) of the theoretical max -- very sparse indeed**. That there was sparseness, we did guess earlier, but that the arrays could be SO sparse -- which matters a lot for memory management -- we had no way of telling till something actually completed, for a real data set. Time taken seems to increase exponentially in input size, but within limits that pose no practical difficulty. Thanks a ton, Ed.

Comment: Could you also add the code of `FII_daily_aggregates_v2.awk`, to make the question stand alone?

Comment: Did so. For reasons I don't understand the END segment would not appear as code, even if highlighted it and did CTRL-K. But that portion above is also part of the code.

Comment: You have a strange way of separating statements on lines 10 & 11. Most people use `statement1; statement2`, but you have `{statement1}{statement2}`. I am intrigued as to why you would do that?

Comment: Are you maybe using a 32-bit version of `awk`? If so, Cygwin offer a 64-bit version... http://www.cygwin.com

Comment: I am using a 32-bit GNU-AWK on a 64-bit machine. Did so even for the 2-array-subscript that worked. Don't understand everything, but Cygwin as an "emulator" was a much bigger thing, consumed more before and during a run. Gnu-Awk being a set of GNU tools "ported natively" to Windows took less space. Doesn't have many std UNIX filters (e.g. head) but enough worked for me. Am trying to switch to Ubuntu on a VM Fusion box. Will take some time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no problem with associative arrays in general. In awk (except gawk for true 2D arrays) an associative array with 4 subscripts is identical to one with 2 subscripts since in reality it only has one subscript which is the concatenation of each of the pseudo-subscripts separated by SUBSEP.

Given you say `I am unable to process more than 6500 lines at a time.` the problem is far more likely to be in the way you wrote your code than any fundamental awk issue so if you'd like more help, post a small script with sample input and expected output that demonstrates your problem and attempted solution to see if we have suggestions on way to improve it's memory usage.

Given your posted script, I expect the problem is with those nested loops in your END section When you do:

```
for (i=1; i<=maxI; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=maxJ; j++) {
        if  ( arr[i,j] != 0 ) {
            print arr[i,j]
        }
    }
}
```

you are CREATING arr[i,j] for every possible combination of i and j that didn't exist prior to the loop just by testing for `arr[i,j] != 0`. If you instead wrote:

```
for (i=1; i<=maxI; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=maxJ; j++) {
        if  ( (i,j) in arr ) {
            print arr[i,j]
        }
    }
}
```

then the loop itself would not create new entries in `arr[]`.

So change this block:

```
if (BNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]] + SNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]] > 0)
{
    BR = BNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
    SR = SNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
    BS = BSH[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
    BV = BRV[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
    SS = SSH[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
    SV = SRV[date_list[u],isin_list[v],exch_list[w],fii_list[x]]
```

which is probably unnecessarily turning each of BNR, SNR, BSH, BRV, SSH, and SRV into huge but highly sparse arrays, to something like this:

```
idx = date_list[u] SUBSEP isin_list[v] SUBSEP exch_list[w] SUBSEP fii_list[x]
BR = (idx in BNR ? BNR[idx] : 0)
SR = (idx in SNR ? SNR[idx] : 0)
if ( (BR + SR) > 0 )
{
    BS = (idx in BSH ? BSH[idx] : 0)
    BV = (idx in BRV ? BRV[idx] : 0)
    SS = (idx in SSH ? SSH[idx] : 0)
    SV = (idx in SRV ? SRV[idx] : 0)
```

and let us know if that helps. Also check your code for other places where you might be doing the same.

The reason you have this problem with 4 subscripts when you didn't with 2 is simply that you have 4 levels of nesting in the loops now creating much larger and more sparse arrays when when you just had 2.

Finally - you have some weird syntax in your script, some of which @MarkSetchell pointed out in a comment, and your script isn't as efficient as it could be since you're not using `else` statements and so testing for multiple conditions that can't possibly all be true and you're testing the same condition repeatedly, and it's not robust as you aren't anchoring your REs (e.g you test `/4|1[13]/` instead of `/^(4|1[13])$/` so for example your `4` would match on `14` or `41` etc. instead of just `4` on its own) so change your whole script to this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }
# For each array subscript variable -- DATE ($10), firm_ISIN ($9), EXCHANGE ($12), and FII_ID ($5), after checking for type = EQ, set up counts for each value, and number of unique values.
$17 ~ /_EQ\>/ {
    if (!seenDate[$10]++) date_list[++d] = $10
    if (!seenIsin[$9]++)  isin_list[++i] = $9
    if (!seenExch[$12]++) exch_list[++e] = $12
    if (!seenFii[$5]++)   fii_list[++f]  = $5

    # For cash-in, buy (B), or cash-out, sell (S) count NR = no of records, SH = no of shares, RV = rupee-value.
    idx = $10 SUBSEP $9 SUBSEP $12 SUBSEP $5
    if ( $11 ~ /^([12359]|1[24])$/ ) {
        ++BNR[idx]; BSH[idx] += $15; BRV[idx] += $16
    }
    else if ( $11 ~ /^(4|1[13])$/ ) {
        ++SNR[idx]; SSH[idx] += $15; SRV[idx] += $16
    }
}
END {
    print NR, "records processed."
    print "  "
    printf "%-11s\t%-13s\t%-20s\t%-19s\t%-7s\t%-7s\t%-14s\t%-14s\t%-18s\t%-18s\n",
           "DATE", "ISIN", "EXCH", "FII", "BNR", "SNR", "BSH", "SSH", "BRV", "SRV"
    for (u = 1; u <= d; u++)
    {
        for (v = 1; v <= i; v++)
        {
            for (w = 1; w <= e; w++)
            {
                for (x = 1; x <= f; x++)
                {
                    #check first below for records with zeroes, don't print them
                    idx = date_list[u] SUBSEP isin_list[v] SUBSEP exch_list[w] SUBSEP fii_list[x]
                    BR = (idx in BNR ? BNR[idx] : 0)
                    SR = (idx in SNR ? SNR[idx] : 0)
                    if ( (BR + SR) > 0 )
                    {
                        BS = (idx in BSH ? BSH[idx] : 0)
                        BV = (idx in BRV ? BRV[idx] : 0)
                        SS = (idx in SSH ? SSH[idx] : 0)
                        SV = (idx in SRV ? SRV[idx] : 0)
                        printf "%-11s\t%13s\t%20s\t%19s\t%7d\t%7d\t%14d\t%14d\t%18.2f\t%18.2f\n",
                            date_list[u], isin_list[v], exch_list[w], fii_list[x], BR, SR, BS, SS, BV, SV
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added `seen` in front of 4 array names just because by convention arrays testing for the pre-existence of a value are typically named `seen`. Also, when populating the SNR[] etc arrays I created an idx variable first instead of repeatedly using the field numbers every time for both ease of changing it in future and mostly because string concatenation is relatively slow in awk and that's whats happening when you use multiple indices in an array so best to just do the string concatenation once explicitly. And I changed your date_list[] etc arrays to start at 1 instead of zero because all awk-generated arrays, strings and field numbers start at 1. You CAN create an array manually that starts at 0 or -357 or whatever number you want but it'll save shooting yourself in the foot some day if you always start them at 1.

I expect it could be made more efficient still by restricting the nested loops to only values that could exist for the enclosing loop index combinations (e.g. not every value of u+v+w is possible so there will be times when you shouldn't bother looping on x). For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }
# For each array subscript variable -- DATE ($10), firm_ISIN ($9), EXCHANGE ($12), and FII_ID ($5), after checking for type = EQ, set up counts for each value, and number of unique values.
$17 ~ /_EQ\>/ {
    if (!seenDate[$10]++) date_list[++d] = $10
    if (!seenIsin[$9]++)  isin_list[++i] = $9
    if (!seenExch[$12]++) exch_list[++e] = $12
    if (!seenFii[$5]++)   fii_list[++f]  = $5

    # For cash-in, buy (B), or cash-out, sell (S) count NR = no of records, SH = no of shares, RV = rupee-value.
    idx = $10 SUBSEP $9 SUBSEP $12 SUBSEP $5
    if ( $11 ~ /^([12359]|1[24])$/ ) {
        seen[$10,$9]
        seen[$10,$9,$12]
        ++BNR[idx]; BSH[idx] += $15; BRV[idx] += $16
    }
    else if ( $11 ~ /^(4|1[13])$/ ) {
        seen[$10,$9]
        seen[$10,$9,$12]
        ++SNR[idx]; SSH[idx] += $15; SRV[idx] += $16
    }
}
END {
    printf "d = %d\n", d | "cat>&2"
    printf "i = %d\n", i | "cat>&2"
    printf "e = %d\n", e | "cat>&2"
    printf "f = %d\n", f | "cat>&2"

    print NR, "records processed."
    print "  "
    printf "%-11s\t%-13s\t%-20s\t%-19s\t%-7s\t%-7s\t%-14s\t%-14s\t%-18s\t%-18s\n",
           "DATE", "ISIN", "EXCH", "FII", "BNR", "SNR", "BSH", "SSH", "BRV", "SRV"
    for (u = 1; u <= d; u++)
    {
        date = date_list[u]
        for (v = 1; v <= i; v++)
        {
            isin = isin_list[v]
            if ( (date,isin) in seen )
            {
                for (w = 1; w <= e; w++)
                {
                    exch = exch_list[w]
                    if ( (date,isin,exch) in seen )
                    {
                        for (x = 1; x <= f; x++)
                        {
                            fii = fii_list[x]
                            #check first below for records with zeroes, don't print them
                            idx = date SUBSEP isin SUBSEP exch SUBSEP fii
                            if ( (idx in BNR) || (idx in SNR) )
                            {
                                if (idx in BNR)
                                {
                                    bnr = BNR[idx]
                                    bsh = BSH[idx]
                                    brv = BRV[idx]
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    bnr = bsh = brv = 0
                                }

                                if (idx in SNR)
                                {
                                    snr = SNR[idx]
                                    ssh = SSH[idx]
                                    srv = SRV[idx]
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    snr = ssh = srv = 0
                                }

                                printf "%-11s\t%13s\t%20s\t%19s\t%7d\t%7d\t%14d\t%14d\t%18.2f\t%18.2f\n",
                                    date, isin, exch, fii, bnr, snr, bsh, ssh, brv, srv
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to upload any attachment. Is inserting code, sample data, expected output, etc directly, the only way to add this information. Will trim code to its bare essentials, and edit the question itself.

Comment: If you need to upload attachments then you're providing too much data. I just updated my answer based on your posted code segment.

Comment: Will digest this slowly, piece by piece. You are very right about sparseness. I thought I was catching that with my "is SNR+BNR>0?" check but didn't realize that the array element is still created. Will modify code, rerun, and post my experience. That the old 2-array subscript code (using an SO suggestion, was pure magic after I wasted my life SORTing) can still be improved is interesting. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I just added another example at the end that shows how to make it more efficient by only executing the child loop when the values from the parent loops existed in your input. I don't know if the stuff about adding BR and SR and comparing with zero `if ( (BR + SR) > 0 )` makes sense for your input or if you should be using a test like `if ( (idx in BNR) || (idx in SNR) )`. Just think about it a bit. I would be very interested in the results to see if there was a performance improvement and if it eliminated some incorrect results due to the previously unanchored RE matching.

Comment: BR = (idx in BNR ? BNR[idx] : 0)
SR = (idx in SNR ? SNR[idx] : 0)
if ( (BR + SR) > 0 )

Comment: Need to understand segment below, as test data may be too small to show up a problem, and actual data too large to check anything manually. And just not having syntax errors and seeing expected output with test data may not be enough. Can't locate a manual entry to explain what the following lines do. Guessing may be dangerous.

BR = (idx in BNR ? BNR[idx] : 0)
SR = (idx in SNR ? SNR[idx] : 0)
if ( (BR + SR) > 0 )

Comment: Not dangerous in the slightest, they're simply using a ternary expression to decide if an index `idx` is populated in the array `BNR` and if so set `BR` to it's value but otherwise set `BR` to zero. It's common, everyday stuff - google "ternary operator".

Comment: Missed your last comment before I posted. `if ( (idx in BNR) || (idx in SNR) )` IS the exclusive-OR idea I want, and more direct than my `if ( (BR + SR) > 0 )' But I don't understand exactly what the RHS in `BR = (idx in BNR ? BNR[idx] : 0)` does.

Comment: Like I say, it's just a common and garden ternary operator. `BR = (idx in BNR ? BNR[idx] : 0)` is equivalent to `if (idx in BNR) BR = BNR[idx]; else BR = 0`.

Comment: Because we have only public data, 'saving on a child loop if the parent loop doesn't reach some value,' will be possible only firms listed only on some exchange. The regulator who will have non-public info (esp on FIIs) can make his loop far more efficient. Because most Indian firms trade on both of the large exchanges, for me the saving for now doesn't seem big. So if this runs ... Will try this out after my classes today.

Comment: Meant NON-exclusive OR.

Comment: First report: on test data, yields expected output. Since I have to run back to teach another class, I decided not to test progressively larger files but just gave as input one compressed file (using zcat instead of cat) downloaded directly from the regulator's website, which has 49,300 records. Has been running 17 minutes -- with no errors but not yet completing. When I got all my earlier error messages, they happened within a minute. So I am praying this will work.

Comment: Given AWK's line-by-line model when I give input from multiple files using zcat *, is it relevant to worry about how many records exist in all the files taken together (i.e. internally, is it like just one big file for GAWK) or should I worry only about the size of the biggest single file?

Comment: Think I can answer my own last question. The arrays in question will reflect ALL the input files taken together.

Comment: Wow, Ed! That is one of the most comprehensive, well-reasoned and well-explained answers I have seen! I hope everyone reads it, digests it, upvotes it and accepts it!

Comment: Thanks you Mark, apparently I'm having a slow day at work :-). @Murgie - I updated the final example to use the `if ( (idx in BNR) || (idx in SNR) )` test instead of `if ( (BR + SR) > 0 )`.

Comment: C:\Users\krishnanm\Documents\PAPERS\FII_Transaction_Data>zcat RAW_DATA\2003_1.zi
p | gawk -f CODE\test.awk > OUTPUT\2003_1.txt

C:\Users\krishnanm\Documents\PAPERS\FII_Transaction_Data>wc -l OUTPUT\2003_1.txt

  38325 OUTPUT\2003_1.txt

Comment: 49300 records processed.
  
DATE        ISIN          EXCH                 FII                 BNR     SNR     BSH            SSH            BRV                SRV               
12/31/2002   INE275A01028  E745964372330200212   F9907886878200212       0       1              0           3500               0.00          985110.00

Comment: Is it working now then? How long does it take to execute now vs on your old script (for the number of records your old script could handle)? I tweaked it again a couple of mins ago to take advantage of the fact that when BNR is populated so are the other B* arrays so you don't need to test for `idx in` all of them but that should only cause a slight performance improvement.

Comment: During a quiz, went back to check and the machine had finished. Thanks. So about 50 min to process 49300 lines. Approx # of non-zero lines = 125 dates * 2 exchanges * 3000 stocks * 10000 FIIs (wild guess, foreign institutions) = 750,000,000. Times 6 variables = 4.5 billion values. The mess is partly I think inherent in the problem. Because we can't trust the regulator to even have the date order right, we can't write one line of output till we're ready to write all lines, and these must be held in memory. And prior SORT, I know from bitter personal experience, is 1000 times worse.

Comment: The only way I can think of to simplify is to use smaller chunks of input, recognize that a given record of aggregate values may be split across several output files.

Comment: What would be the benefit of splitting it up? Unless you have different processors to run it on, it'd still take the same aggregate amount of time to run, maybe more.

Comment: Since the number of output lines = 38325 for 49300 input records, my guess about the average number of FIIs trading each day has to be horribly wrong! Even the number of stocks with FII interest must be very small. So solving sparseness has been the key. Have never seen SUBSEP used like this.

Comment: I agree, splitting doesn't promise much. With these jobs in background, I don't have to babysit the machine either.

Comment: I can't imagine why it'd take anything close to 50 mins to read 50K lines and output 40K lines. I'd have expected that to take less than 1 min. Please try running `time awk -f script file` and post the output of `time`. I just updated the script to print the number of exchanges, fiis, etc to stderr (see the 4 printf statements at the top of the END section) so that will tell us what those values actually are too.

Comment: Will run at least clock-time comparisons when I go home. Don't know how to give a Win-7 command that will return time taken. Will Google for it later. For sure your suggested code is able to do things on files an order of magnitude larger than files on which my old code simply gave up. Thanks a TON.

Comment: Oh, you're on the dreaded Windows. Not sure how to print to stderr on that, piping to "cat>&2" may not work. If I were you I'd install cygwin and run on that.

Comment: Just so you know. The code I ran was your first suggestion, modified for using if `( (idx in BNR) || (idx in SNR) )` instead of  if `( (BR + SR) > 0 )` Yet to try with the "seen" variables inserted to minimize loops. Will do that later today.

Comment: C:\Users\krishnanm\Documents\PAPERS\FII_Transaction_Data>zcat RAW_DATA\2003_2.zip | wc -l
  76497

C:\Users\krishnanm\Documents\PAPERS\FII_Transaction_Data>zcat RAW_DATA\2003_2.zip | gawk -f Code\tst.awk > OUTPUT\2003_2.txt
d = 144
i = 588
e = 24
f = 1520

C:\Users\krishnanm\Documents\PAPERS\FII_Transaction_Data>ls -l OUTPUT
total 14675
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group     5825126 Sep 30 14:57 2003_1.txt
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group     9201046 Sep 30 16:11 2003_2.txt

C:\Users\krishnanm\Documents\PAPERS\FII_Transaction_Data>wc -l OUTPUT\2003_2.txt

  60535 OUTPUT\2003_2.txt

Comment: Used tst.awk. Clock time to produce 2003_2.txt from 2003_2.zip -- maybe TWO minutes!!! Ed, you are a magician! 76497 input records yielded 60535 output records. Also, my estimates of d, i, e, f were all off. "e" (# exchanges) is misleading because the 2 largest account for 99.999% of all activity. But shows how my old code multiplied the sparse rows enormously. I still need to wrap my head around your use of "seen[$10,$9]," etc. It has made an almighty difference. I wrongly interpreted your 'parent-loop, child-loop' comment as 'study the actual economic setting and impose constraints."

Comment: For 2003_2.zip (2nd half of 2003) we had 76497 input records which yielded 60535 output records. Dates d = 144, ISINs i = 588, EXCHANGES e = 24, and FIIs f = 1520. So the max size would have been 144*588*24*1520 = 3,088,834,560. Yet we have only 60,535 output records, which is about 1.95*10^(-5). This is sparse.

Comment: Piping to stderr does work even on windows, at least with GNU UNX-UTILS in the PATH. The diagnostic info was tremendously helpful in realizing how sparse the arrays were. Will try the time function. Code which worked yesterday on 6500 lines did NOT work today. tst.awk has processed even a 200K+ file, albeit it took about 11 minutes for that. The next few files, till the 2008 crash, will be getting bigger. Off to yoga and to stand on my head! Thanks.

Comment: 64-bit Win-7 has some trouble using built-in time commands. So I just used %time% before and after lines to run your gawk script in a batch file. So we at least get clock time. Some statistics:         filename  start         end       min in ln  out lines
2008_1 12:08:40 AM 12:27:18 AM 0:18 391438 301160
2008_2 12:27:18 AM 12:52:04 AM 0:24 402016 314177
2009_1 12:52:05 AM 1:05:15 AM 0:13 302081 238204
2009_2 1:05:15 AM 1:22:15 AM 0:17 360072 276768

Comment: Don't know how to preserve a table in a comment. But for  4 big files run-time went from 13 to 24 min, as input size went from 302081 lines to 402016, and output lines went from 238204 to 314177. Used essentially your last version of tst.awk (because of some changes in input format in later files, e.g. all fields in quotes, fixed width in some fields, had to make minor changes)

Comment: Think there is a highly exponential relationship between input size and time. More statistics below. The old code couldn't have finished anything. For 4 more files (from late 2010) for input lines from 76200 to 86923, output lines from 58228 to 65885, EXCEL rounded the time taken to 0 min, i.e. less than a minute. But this is suggesting that breaking up into chunks may make a difference.

Comment: Edited 1 line in afterword, in the Question, after processing our entire data, for the degree of sparseness. The ratio of the actual number of output lines, to the theoretical max, is about 1.275*10^(-8).